# group two columns of the same table with the same values and sum the values

Tags: mysql

I need the idmo and sum the Qty where idmo in idmc (Qty1) and also have idmo where it is not in idmc excluding the idmo that are in idmc as well as making the Qty1 - r (Qty2) of result

this is the example table

```
+-------------------------------------+
| MyTable                             |
+------+------+------+-----+----+-----+
| idcl | idmo | idmc | cat | r  | Qty |
+------+------+------+-----+----+-----+
| 1    | 8010 | 0    | 4   | 3  | 1   |
| 1    | 8011 | 8010 | 5   | 0  | 1   |
| 1    | 8012 | 8010 | 5   | 0  | 1   |
| 1    | 8013 | 0    | 4   | 50 | 1   |
+------+------+------+-----+----+-----+
```

this is the result I would like to achieve

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| right result                                |
+------+------+------+-----+----+------+------+
| idcl | idmo | idmc | cat | r  | Qty1 | Qty2 |
+------+------+------+-----+----+------+------+
| 1    | 8010 | 0    | 4   | 3  |  2   |  1   |
| 1    | 8013 | 0    | 4   | 50 |  0   |  50  |
+------+------+------+-----+----+------+------+
```

i tried to get it with this query

```
SELECT 
MyTable.idcl AS idcl, 
MyTable.idmo AS idmo,
MyTable.idmc AS idmc,
MyTable.cat AS cat,
MyTable.r AS r,
  Sum(((MyTable.cat = '4') * MyTable.Qty)) AS Qty1,
  Sum(((MyTable.cat = '5') * MyTable.Qty)) AS Qty2,
MyTable.Data AS Data
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.Data IS NULL
GROUP BY (CASE
    WHEN (idmo IN (SELECT idmc)) THEN idmo
    WHEN (idmo NOT IN (SELECT idmc) AND idmc = 0) THEN idmo
    END)
```

but I get this

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| result                                      |
+------+------+------+-----+----+------+------+
| idcl | idmo | idmc | cat | r  | Qty1 | Qty2 |
+------+------+------+-----+----+------+------+
| 1    | 8010 | 0    | 4   | 3  |  0   |  1   |
| 1    | 8011 | 8010 | 5   |    |  2   |  0   |
| 1    | 8013 | 0    | 4   | 50 |  0   |  1   |
+------+------+------+-----+----+------+------
```

I also tried with joins but I didn't get the "right result". It sounds simple but I can't develop it with just one query

Comment: columns in the select list do not conform with the result set.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You need a hierarchical query, available in MySQL 8.x.

Comment: what's  hierarchical query?